# dompdf: templates & $_SESSION variables

Tags: templates, session, dompdf

i was wondering if this setup would work.  i have to crank out a batch of PDF from a bunch of variables i'm pushing into the $_SESSION via a form (duh...).  the idea is to pass the template file to the dompdf engine and have the template populate from the $_SESSION then out to PDF.  it seems to me that when the $template gets loaded it should do that, yes?

here's the basic code:

```
<?php
function renderToPDF($theTemplate = "template.php") // this is just to show the value
{
  require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

  $content = file_get_contents($theTemplate); 

  if ($content !== false)
  {
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($content);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("kapow_ItWorks.pdf");
  }
}
?>
```

and this is the `template.php` file (basically... you don't want all 16 pages...)

```
<html>
<meta>
<head>
  <link href="thisPage.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
  <body>
    <h1><?php echo $_SESSION['someTitle'] ?></h1>
    <h2>wouldn't it be nice, <?php echo $_SESSION['someName'] ?></h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

so my thinking is that the template.php will pull the variables right out of the `$_SESSION` array without any intervention, looking like this:

## BIG TITLE

### wouldn't it be nice, HandsomeLulu?

i guess the nut of the question is: Do `$_SESSION` variables get evaluated when PHP files are loaded, but not rendered?

WR!

Comment: i found something that might answer part of my question in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248199/dompdf-loading-html-files-to-render-doesnt-work) (Wrikken's answer).  i'm on a flight right now or i'd have a system i could test this on...  :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for some reason, the code ON the page that calls the function ALSO gets dumped into the file.  this was placed before the header.  i understand now why: i wasn't *referencing* an external page, i was *importing* and external page.  don't know why that didn't click.

anyway.  as soon as i got rid of the page's extra stuff, it worked just fine.  in retrospect, what dompdf needed to state was quite simply that NO HTML of ANY kind (echo, print, &c.) can be on the page that calls the function.  at least that what it appears to require at this level of my knowledge.

for those who, like me, are floundering in a misma of 'everything but the answer', here's the bare bones code that did the job:

`buildPDF.php:`

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['someTitle'] = "BIG FAT TITLE";
$_SESSION['someName'] = "HandomeLu";

$theTemplate = 'template.php';

function renderToPDF($templateFile)
{
  require_once("_dox/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
  ob_start();
  include $templateFile;
  $contents = ob_get_clean(); 

  if ($contents !== false)
  {
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($contents);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("kapow_ItWorks.pdf");
 }
}

renderToPDF($theTemplate);
?>
```

and this is the `template.php:`

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <meta>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link href="thisPage.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1><?php echo $_SESSION['someTitle'] ?></h1>
      <p>wouldn't it be nice, <?php echo $_SESSION['someName'] ?></p>
    </body>
   </html>
```

also note that the external CSS file reads in just fine.  so you can still keep the structure and style separate.  also, the $_SESSION variables can be set anywhere, obviously, i just set them here to keep testing easy.

hope this is useful for those getting started with this GREAT class.  if you're looking to get up and running cranking out PDF files, this kicks so much butt, it should have a trigger and a grip on it.  :)

thanks to everyone who commented.  you got me in the place i needed to be.  :)

this site ROCKS.

WR!

Answer (score 2):

`file_get_contents` does not evaluate the PHP file, it simply gets its contents (the file as it is in the hard drive).

To do what you want, you need to use output [buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.outcontrol.php) and `include`.

```
ob_start(); // Start Output beffering
include $theTemplate; // include the file and evaluate it : all the code outside of <?php ?> is like doing an `echo`
$content = ob_get_clean(); // retrieve what was outputted and close the OB
```

Comment: okay.  we're cooking with gas now!  totally makes sense!  i was looking into output buffering; thrilled i was on the right track!  :D  i get an error when the PDF file tried to open, but i think i've seen the answer to that in my research: "...could not open because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged."  i think we're almost all there!  thank you so very much!  :D

Comment: i was mistaken.  it was a different error.  i'll keep looking unless you guys have seen this kind of error before...

Comment: The usual suspect for this kind of problem is output buffering causing PHP warnings/notices to be placed at the top of the PDF file. You can check for this by opening the PDF in a text editor.

Comment: i'd love to! ...how do i do that?  :D  i looked at the PDF in a text editor and i saw no errors there.  mind you, i'm not sure what i'm looking for.  you can DL the outputted PDF [here](http://hotfile.com/dl/133557830/59aa5cc/fileOut.pdf.html)

Comment: i thought that might be the case, but when i tried tearing that out, it just wouldn't open.  "file is damaged or corrupted and cannot be repaired".  this is bugging the hell out of me.  :(  how do i clean the HTML out of the output buffer dump?  isn't that the whole point of using the output buffer?  to parse the PHP and then send it to the dompdf?  argh!

Comment: @Fabien: you missed (as did i) that the file doesn't wrap up properly either.  all the 'footer' data is gone.  the stream doesn't close, and no #EOF.  compare against a PDF from the demo01.php and you'll see what i mean.  i think i should move this over to somewhere else.  doesn't seem like anyone here can really help.  :P