# dompdf not rending post variables

Tags: php, pdf-generation, dompdf

creating a PDF with DOM PDF the pdf creates fine, but the post variables arent in the pdf. For example  the "$_POST["docnumber"]" would  not be in the PDF. If I echo val right before it renders everything appears to be filled in fine.

It might just be I am very tired :-)

Here is an example code:

```
<?
require("../application.php");
require_once("../dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

$val = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<title>Application</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<form action="" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td><div id="officeuseonly_left">
<div align="center">OFFICE USE ONLY</div><br /><br />
 Document Control #<br />
 <input type="text" name="docnumber" id="docnumber" value = "' . $_POST["docnumber"] .   '"     /><br /><br />
 By <input type="text" name="by" id="by" value = ""' . $_POST["by"] .'" /><br />
 </div></td>

 <tr>

  <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /></p>
  </form>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>';

  if (isset($_POST["submit"])){

  $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
  $dompdf->load_html($val);
  $dompdf->render();
  $dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");        
}
else
{
   echo $val;

}
```

Comment: can you explain me more... it will be more usefull to help you

Comment: the variable **`$_POST["docnumber"]`** is not present in the code where is it ?

Comment: can you show how your output file how it looks ?

Comment: Hi varun sure. Give me just a few minutes Ill put a complete working xample together.  What i put there a brief snippet of a MUCH large file to demonstrate the concept. I am pretty sure it is something silly I am doing :-)

Comment: Here is a complete working example. Its in the post above Ill be looking at this here in a few minutes will let you know what find.

Comment: I think I found a very relvant answer already out there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920218/dompdf-templates-session-variables