# Save PDF file with Dompdf

Tags: php, laravel-5, dompdf

using Dompdf to store data in pdf file:

This function work fine :

```
$pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
$pdf->loadHTML('<h1>Test</h1> ');
return $pdf->stream();
```

Now,when try

```
$pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
$pdf->loadHTML('<h1>Test</h1> ');
file_put_contents("test.pdf", $pdf->output());
```

Get error:

```
file_put_contents(test.pdf): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Do I need to create some extra folder for saving file or something ?

Tnx, P

Comment: Quiet simple, you don't have the sufficient rights to write to the folder / directory? Check that you're webuser has the required read/write to folder and file.

Comment: Hi,tnx for time ! That is ok, I alsto try with specific path, same error... But I can't find in documentation in which folder will be this file saved, so to know what perrmision to change...

Comment: you can check this link for better solution . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60795346/how-to-save-dompdf-file-to-storage-and-name-the-file-dynamicly-in-laravel/74942859#74942859

Answer (score 12):

To **save** the generated `pdf` to a file, use `output()`, e.g.:

```
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('<h1>hello world</h1>');
$output = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents('filename.pdf', $output);
```

Comment: Use may use a path too: file_put_contents('/home/website/public_html/aap_path/temp/filename.pdf', $output);

Comment: Yes,  you can also use an absolute path instead of a relative.

Answer (score 2):

This resolve problem :

```
  return PDF::loadHTML('<h1>Test</h1> ')->save('path-/my_stored_file.pdf');
```

This question help:

[dompdf: loading html files to render, doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248199/dompdf-loading-html-files-to-render-doesnt-work)

Tnx,
P

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$pdf->load_html('<h1>Test</h1>');
$pdf->render();
$pdf->stream("data.pdf");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the permissions of the folder. (0777)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMH76.png)

```
    $pdf->load_html('<h1>Test</h1>');
    $pdf->render();
    $output = $pdf->output();
    file_put_contents('./historialCartera/prueba.pdf', $output);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYlIm.png)